# In decorator chaining did the function we pass to the decorator get executed twice?

Tags: python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, decorator-chaining

```
def pass_through1(func):
    def inner1(*args):
        test_logs.append("pt1")
        return func(*args)
    return inner1

def pass_through2(func):
    def inner2(*args):
        test_logs.append("pt2")
        return func(*args)
    return inner2

@pass_through1
@pass_through2
def increment(num):
    return num+1

test_logs=[]
increment(10) //gives me the answer as 11
test_logs=['pt1','pt2'] //now test_log contains after the calling the increment function
```

Now my doubt is did the increment function gets executed twice? As we are passing it to the two decorators.

Comment: What makes you think the decorated function is called twice? Why would the result be 11 if 10 was incremented twice?

Comment: What makes me to think like that is the test_logs = ['pt1','pt2']  so I thought function might have went through two decorators ,but the below answer clarified my doubt. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing `increment` to both decorators; you pass `increment` to the decorator `pass_through2` and this returns a function named `inner2` which is passed to the other decorator `pass_through1`. That decorator returns a function named `inner1` which is finally bound to the name `increment`.

So when you call `increment`, it really calls `inner1`, which then calls `inner2`, which calls the original `increment` function - once - and each of `inner1` and `inner2` do their logging once.

Comment: Thank you :) My doubt is clarified.